# How to pull dependencies from protected artifactory using grapes in groovy?

Tags: groovy, artifactory, jenkins-groovy, jfrog-cli, groovy-grape

I want to pull dependencies from jfrog artifactory, Artifcatory mandates authentication with access token. Couldnt find a way to pull jars with credentials.